# Attempt to POST to a servlet results in HTTP Status 404 - Could not find resource for relative

Tags: rest, servlets, jax-rs

I've a HTML form:

```
<form action="rest/ws/addNote" method="post">
```

I'm trying to POST to this servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/ws")
public class AddNote extends HttpServlet {

    @POST
    @Path("/addNote")
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But I keep getting

> HTTP Status 404 - Could not find resource for relative : /ws/addNote of full path: http://localhost:8080/project/rest/ws/addNote

Comment: can you give the paths of your this program files?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/project/rest/ws/addNote  is this what you mean>

Comment: are there only one source packages created in the Source packages, or only this one?

Comment: @Shar there is no post request handler in your code. I think you are mixing servlet with jersy REST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending a post request for that you should have a post request handler method there in your servlet. I am assuming you are not using any REST framework. Then your servlet should be:

```
@WebServlet("/rest/ws/addNote")
public class AddNote extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
........
```

Or if you are already using any REST frameworks like **Jersy**, don't use a servlet here.Try some [examples](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ggqnw/index.html)

**Update**

since you are using REST try following instead of servlet:

```
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/ws")
public class AddNote {

    @POST
    @Path("/addNote")
    public Response addUser(
        @FormParam("name") String name,
        @FormParam("age") int age) {
   .........
```

Here I assumed in your `web.xml`, the REST controller servlet mapping is `/rest/*` and your html `<form>` having `<input>` tags with names `name,age`, then the will be passed into the corresponding method arguments as above.

Full example you can see [**here**](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-formparam-example/)

Comment: Yes i'm using rest! all i want to do is write what is in the form to a local file

Comment: Thank you! do i need to add an @Consumes to this?